# How to find the proper glyph name required by \pdfglyphtounicode

Tags: pdftex, unicode

I am creating a PDF using pdfTeX. Alas, the publisher's requirement is that all glyphs therein are mapped to one or more Unicode code points. I got this working for most, but not all glyphs:

```
\input glyphtounicode.tex
\pdfgentounicode=1
```

For two glyphs, namely `\nexists` (U+2204) and `\leftarrowtail` (U+21A2) from `amssymb`, it looks like an need to manually add a `\pdfglyphtounicode`. But I can't find out what to pass as its first parameter, i.e., for the glyph name. Any pointers?

Comment: Try using the updated version of `glyphtounicode.tex` that is distributed with lcdf typetools http://www.lcdf.org/type/

Answer (score 3):

The following works on a TeX Live distribution:

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\ifdefined\pdffontattr
  \immediate\pdfobj stream file {umsa.cmap}
  {\usefont{U}{msa}{m}{n}\pdffontattr\font{/ToUnicode \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R}}
  \immediate\pdfobj stream file {umsb.cmap}
  {\usefont{U}{msb}{m}{n}\pdffontattr\font{/ToUnicode \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R}}
\fi
```

The code binds the MSA and MSB fonts with the appropriate CMAP resources.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to consult the [Unicode Code Charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/)

These two particular cases would appear to be `theredoesnotexist` (2204) and `leftwardsarrowwithtail` (21A2).

These code points also appear in `texglyphlist.txt`, as `notexistential` and `arrowtailleft` respectively. Although this file appears in TeXLive as

```
@/texmf-dist/fonts/map/glyphlist/texglyphlist.txt
```

I can't find it on CTAN.

I must also confess I can't see much point in having *two* sets of names.